# Magento2:How to get address when customer checkout

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-address

I'm develop a module for shipping method. I need order's address to calculate freight.

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

$destCountryId = $request->getDestCountryId();
$destState = $request->getDestRegionCode();
$destCity = $request->getDestCity();
```

If customer not login ,they need to input address like picture
[image]
I can use my code to get address.
But if customer have logined and select address.
[image]
My code can get country and city ,but can't get State with getDestRegionCode().
What's wrong with my code.Or may be someone can tell me how to get address is right.

Comment: Please refer this :- https://meetanshi-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/meetanshi.com/blog/get-customer-addresses-by-customer-id-magento-2/amp/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15873635950754&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fmeetanshi.com%2Fblog%2Fget-customer-addresses-by-customer-id-magento-2%2F

Answer (score 0):

In your Model Carrier, add the following code after "$destPostcode = $request->getDestPostcode();"

```
if ($request->getDestRegionId()) {
        $regionCollection = $this->_regionCollectionFactory->create();
        $regionCollection->addFilter('main_table.region_id', $request->getDestRegionId());
        $region = $regionCollection->getFirstItem();

        $request->setDestRegionCode($region->getCode());
}
$destRegionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();
```

You will also need to add the regionCollecttionFactory to your Constructor:

```
\Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But ,there isn't function setRequest(RateRequest $request) in my Model,what should I do.And ,if customer's state is not select from list is input by heself like 'zhejiang' ,Your code still can help me ?  Please help me agin,thanks.

Comment: @keke996 I updated my answer, please take a look now.

Comment: thanks,and what's function _getQuotes(),i create it before your answer.

Comment: _getQuotes() is the function that will call the API to retrieve the shipping rates, You probably gave a different name to it.

Comment: sorry , I can't find _getQuotes() function in my code,I just $result->append($method) and return in collectRates().
now I add your setRequest() into my code and $this->setRequest($request) in collectRates(), now my page is worng .can't find _countryFactory

Comment: You will need to share your entire model here, otherwise, I won't be able to continue helping you.

Comment: I edit my question , input my model, can you help me?

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer again, it should work now.

Comment: You can also remove all the changes you have done before this.

Comment: Please, put your model back on the original question so other people will also be helped when they face the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: ok , i'm trying your code ,if run right,i will put simple model into question

Comment: Answering your previous question, if the state is not selected from the list, there is no way to Magento to guess what the region code is, so you should not allow customers to manually input a region. If there is a region missing from the list, then add it to the Magento database.

Comment: sorry, destRegionCode  still is null .When I log $request->getDestRegionId().It's null.
May be ,you can tell me how to get address in other way?

Comment: There is no other way of handling this. If you bypass it now, you will have other problems ahead. Verify if your address has a region_id in the database before proceeding.

Comment: in table customer_address_entity region_id is 0  which I can't useing getDestRegionCode() to get region

Comment: Please, add the entire DB entry here, only for that address.

Comment: INSERT INTO `magento`.`customer_address_entity` (`entity_id`, `increment_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `is_active`, `city`, `company`, `country_id`, `fax`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `middlename`, `postcode`, `prefix`, `region`, `region_id`, `street`, `suffix`, `telephone`, `vat_id`, `vat_is_valid`, `vat_request_date`, `vat_request_id`, `vat_request_success`) VALUES ('5', NULL, '4', '2020-04-20 11:34:18', '2020-04-20 11:34:18', '1', 'hangzhou', NULL, 'CN', NULL, 'xiaobai', 'xu', NULL, '310000', NULL, 'zhejiang', '0', 'wenyi', NULL, '15924090000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

Comment: It looks like you manually entered the Region name in the input field, rather than selecting it from a list. Can you please confirm if that is the case? You won't be able to retrieve the region code when you manually enter the region name in an input field. Also try to add a new address, but now selecting the state/province from the list.

Comment: Yes ! I entered Region name in the input field.My code can get region When I entered.
After Checkout ,the address I entered was saved into DB by magento2, then I can select address when  checkout next time.But if address is selected not entered I can't get region also they have same region ( I entered ). There was no way to get region when I checkout by select address ?Anyway region is in Db(in tablecustomer_address_entity but region_id is 0) .

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Is it the region or region code? You can't get the region code if your region was set manually in the input field. In these cases, the region id will always be 0.

Comment: I want to get region , which string customer entered  in 'State/Province' while checkout-Shipping Address.region_id always be 0,but region have value in table customer_address_entity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106979/discussion-on-answer-by-andresa-martins-magento2how-to-get-address-when-custome).